# retrieving information from URL

Tags: php, url

I'm creating an API with PHP and am having difficulty with the URL, it gets this URL to me `http://localhost/api/index/Peoples/3`

The idea is that I want to use the Peoples Class and I want to get the Person with code 3, is there any way I can get Peoples and number 3?

The idea I made was this, I retrieve the URL from the browser and I'm going to explode on it. While I do not need to pass parameters through the url this works perfectly

```
public function getClass(){

        $params = explode("/api/index/", $this->currentUrl);

        if(count($params) == 1)
            return "no have class !";
        else
        { 
            $params = explode('/', $params[1]);

            $this->callClass($params[0]);
            return "Classe : ".$params[0];
        }

    }
```

with this code I can recover Peoples and then know which class I will use. now I want to pass the parameter of the code, as for example 3. I could pass as follows ../Peoples?id=3 but I would have to break even more my string, have a better way to do this?

What's the difference between passing ../Peoples?id=3 or ../Peoples/3 and how can I recover?

Comment: What have you already tried? Please provide the all relevant code

Comment: the short answer is yes, there are ways. What have you done about trying to solve this yourself so far? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback! I edited my question, can I help with anything else?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
public function getClass()
{      
  $path = explode('/', parse_url($this->currentUrl, PHP_URL_PATH));

  if(count($path) !== 5){
      return 'not valid url';
  }

  $id    = array_pop($path);
  $class = array_pop($path);

  //$this->callClass($class);

  $newPath = $class.'?id='.$id;

 return $newPath;
}
```

and regarding your question about /Peoples?id=3 or ../Peoples/3
the second one is easier if you are working with a framework such as symfony or laravel where you can define controllers and the first one you can easily fetch you data from the URL with $_GET['id']

Hope that was what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, but can not I retrieve People/3 equal to $ _GET ['id']?

Comment: Hope I understood your question right. 

when you use people/3 in a framework such as Symfony the framework give you the functionality to fetch these parts as parameters passed to the route. if you are not familiar with framework then I suggest using the other format people?id=3

Comment: That's the very idea, get the person with code 3. but for example, does the framework also do this? Does it recover the url and is it exploding in it? or has some easier way to recover the / 3 without having to explode

Comment: I would suggest you read this for more understanding https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/routing.html